# Strange compiler errors in Eclipse for node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I loaded up some a node.js-express project into my eclipse IDE with the JavaScript perspective. I'm getting a ton of odd errors, including

1. Cannot return from outside a function
2. Syntax Error on token ".",. expected
3. Syntax Error, ; expected

Below is an example of the "return outside function" error.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env node
    'use strict';
    var pkg = require('./package.json');
    var supportsColor = require('./');
    var argv = process.argv.slice(2);

    function help() {
        console.log([
            '',
            '  ' + pkg.description,
            '',
            '  Usage',
            '    supports-color',
            '',
            '  Exits with code 0 if color is supported and 1 if not'
        ].join('\n'));
    }

    if (argv.indexOf('--help') !== -1) {
        help();
        return; //<-error
    }

    if (argv.indexOf('--version') !== -1) {
        console.log(pkg.version);
        return;
    }

    process.exit(supportsColor ? 0 : 1);
```

Here's an example of the "missing ;" error:

```
function createParserGetter(name) {
  return function get() {
    return loadParser(name) //<- error
  }
}
```

I suspect the latter is just a picky parser. The former seems like its an artifact of the fact we are using a framwork (node + express), so the code by itself is not complete (because it will be injected?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. you can't return outside a function: as you can see the if loop is't inside the function help anymore, you can't return in an if.
2. just write a semicolon after: "return loadParser(name)" like this: "return loadParser(name);"

Comment: I know JavaScript syntax...what boggles me is that this program is perfectly functional. I want to know why the errors are not actually errors here.

Comment: OH so: 1. the return statement is just ignored, but the code works still fine cause there is no need for a return in an if statement, if there would be something after the return, or it would return a value, i wouldn't work

Comment: 2. there id nothing after the semicolon, if there would be sth it wouldn't work again, but there isn't anything so it is ignored simply.   In javascript JSLint Errors like that are ignored for exampl: everyone uses "alert()" for testing, but actually it is wrong, you cant use alert like that, so it causes a JSLint Error, but it is simply ignored and fixed by the browser or eclipse for eg.